# Mobx state tree wont re-render screen component in react native

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have the following code

```jsx
import React, { FunctionComponent as Component } from "react"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { useStores } from "../models"

export const LoginScreen: Component = observer(function LoginScreen() {
  const rootStore = useStores()
return (
<Screen>
<Text> {rootStore.counter}</Text>
<Button onPress={() => rootStore.addCounter()} />
</Screen>
)
})
```

But when i press the button the component text wont update, it only displays the incremented number after refreshing/restarting the app.

How do i get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet and wanted to ask you to share the source for the store if possible. But I'm taking a shot here:

a) Is your `addCounter()` in the `rootStore` properly wrapped as an action?

b) Is your `counter` observable?